# Automatically format code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a long time visual studio developer and am stating with VS Code.

I found the **Format Code** shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) but I want it to run automatically whenever I press `;`. Is there a configuration for that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can choose one of the below options

```
"editor.formatOnType": false,
"editor.formatOnPaste": false,
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

Or create a custom keyboard shortcut by editing `editor.action.formatDocument`. But I AFAIK there is no option to execute the command whenever you press `;`. You can set a keyboard shortcut, but I guess you're not able to write `;` anymore then :D

Comment: Could you add to your answer how to change those settings?

Comment: You can find how to change settings in the official documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: This was written for React but it works for all
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/automatically-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-when-working-with-react-c48674a12dc5

Answer (score 11):

To open your [user and workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), use the following VS Code menu command:

> On Windows/Linux - File > Preferences > Settings
>
> On macOS - Code > Preferences > Settings

Add these options to the editable panel of your configuration settings:

```
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find the answer to the semicolon format thing, because it was doing it on my old computer but not my new one. You just have to change `editor.formatOnType = true` in your JSON config settings.