# Why do items in the NgModule realign when I save?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to keep the items in my NgModule in a vertical list like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ 
  AppComponent, 
  PostCreateComponent ],
imports: [ 
  BrowserModule, 
  FormsModule, 
  BrowserAnimationsModule, 
  MatInputModule, 
  MatCardModule ],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

But as soon as I save, Angular automatically reverts it back to a horizontal list like this:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [ AppComponent, PostCreateComponent ],
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, ....
providers: [],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
```

Comment: What ide do you use?

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk  VSCode

Comment: This answer can help I guess https://stackoverflow.com/a/43248309/6528560

Answer (score 0):

You probably have auto-format code on save enabled in your IDE