# How to change Visual Studio Code's autocomplete to be the same as Visual Studio Community's?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is there a setting that automatically inserts whitespaces into the code when you enter a semicolon?

For example,

```
cout<<"Hello world!"<<endl
```

to

```
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
```

[image]

[image]

If you type `;` in Visual Studio (as seen above), it will automatically insert whitespaces. Is there a setting similar to this in VS Code?

Comment: There are extensions.for vscode that use clang-format m.  It may not work exactly like visual studio.  But it is a place to start.

Comment: Note that this question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404529).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically format code in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247742/automatically-format-code-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 4):

In Settings, under `Text Editor` is "Formatting". In here, turn on "Format On Type". This will cause it to auto-format after putting in a semicolon.

If it still doesn't format it after this, you'll probably have to go under `Extensions` to your language (which in this case is `C/C++`), scroll down until you see `C_Cpp > Vc Format`, and change any formatting you want.